# Get user Account form

Tags: 7, forms, users

I am trying the user account form(the one that comes in *user/%/edit*) of the logged in user, I have tried:

```
drupal_get_form('user_profile_form');
```

&

```
drupal_get_form('user_profile_form',1);
```

Though the form is loaded, on calling `render()` the div is empty.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The second example won't work because `user_profile_form()` takes a user object as it's argument, not an id. I suspect your form is not being outputted because you're not actually calling `print` on it...`render()` just prepares the string it doesn't actually output it.

Try this code:

```
$account = user_load(1);
print render(drupal_get_form('user_profile_form', $account));
```

**EDIT**

You'll also need to include the user.pages.inc file where the function itself lives:

```
module_load_include('inc', 'user', 'user.pages');
```

Comment: That did not work either. Gives the same output.

Comment: It works fine for me, where are you calling the code from?

Comment: From a custom module, but I finally got it to work, I had to include the `user.pages.inc` form the user module. Thanks. can you edit your answer to add the above point?

Comment: @karthik Ah yes my bad, I already had that file included :) I've updated the answer to put that in